# Firefox rendering inconsistently and with black areas on redraw

Tags: html, css, firefox, rendering

I have a site (http://www.iproconnect.com.au/) that for one user (that I know of) renders the home page with black areas in Firefox. These do not seem to be tied to CSS, as if I force a re-draw of an affected area (e.g. by scrolling areas in and out of the viewport) it sometimes renders correctly, and sometimes incorrectly but differently to the previous incorrectly. Also if I do this with the inspector open, no CSS seems to change, and hovering background URLs show the image downloaded correctly.

I can't reproduce this in other installations of Firefox (all running the same version - fully up to date). And this user has un-installed and re-installed with no change in behavior.

I don't even know how to debug this further, let alone how to solve. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have been designing a website and have seen some graphical glitches on one individual's computer with Firefox. It's Windows 7 with the newest version (39).

The problem on my side is weird graphical artifacts and even loading the wrong image on objects that have a background-url. When you hover, the image is correct.

I can't reproduce this bug on my devices, so it looks like a rather unusual bug though I can't find much info about this issue.

Comment: That sounds almost exactly the issue I'm having. Let me know if you make any ground.

Comment: I'm probably not going to do anything. I feel like it's a silly browser-specific bug that will go away soon.